# Error with cbind on two xts objects

Tags: r, xts

This should be fairly simple for veteran R programmers but I can't seem to find a solution online.

I'm trying to bind a column from a xts object `sym.rank` to the end of a second existing object `A` but the results increases the number of rows. The data from `sym.rank` is essentially shifted down instead of being correctly aligned to the data in `A`.

```
> str(A)
An ‘xts’ object on 2005-01-31/2012-12-31 containing:
Data: num [1:96, 1:6] 35.5 33.8 33.6 33.3 31.9 ...
-attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : NULL
..$ : chr [1:6] "XLY.Open" "XLY.High" "XLY.Low" "XLY.Close" ...
Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
xts Attributes:  
List of 2
$ src    : chr "yahoo"
$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-01-27 00:42:13"

> str(sym.rank)
An ‘xts’ object on 2005-01-31/2012-12-31 containing:
Data: num [1:96, 1:5] NA NA 5 5 4 2 2 3 5 5 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : NULL
..$ : chr 
[1:5] "XLY.Adjusted" "XLP.Adjusted" "XLE.Adjusted" "AGG.Adjusted" ...
Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
xts Attributes:  
NULL

>sym.rank
       XLY.Adjusted XLP.Adjusted XLE.Adjusted AGG.Adjusted IVV.Adjusted
2005-01-31           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
2005-02-28           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
2005-03-31            5            3            1            4            2
2005-04-30            5            2            4            1            3
2005-05-31            4            3            5            1            2
2005-06-30            2            5            1            4            3

> A
       XLY.Open XLY.High XLY.Low XLY.Close XLY.Volume XLY.Adjusted
2005-01-31    35.45    35.55   33.23     33.78    5464600     28.49650
2005-02-28    33.82    34.36   33.33     33.60    5813500     28.34465
2005-03-31    33.60    34.40   32.71     33.16   10675600     28.01342
2005-04-30    33.30    33.47   30.62     31.05   12504000     26.23090
2005-05-31    31.92    33.18   31.04     32.97    9032100     27.85291
2005-06-30    33.10    33.88   32.68     32.78    7248700     27.73284

> cbind(A,sym.rank[,1])
       XLY.Open XLY.High XLY.Low XLY.Close XLY.Volume XLY.Adjusted XLY.Adjusted.1
2005-01-30       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA            NA             NA
2005-01-31    35.45    35.55   33.23     33.78    5464600     28.49650             NA
2005-02-27       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA             NA
2005-02-28    33.82    34.36   33.33     33.60    5813500     28.34465             NA
2005-03-30       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA           NA              5
2005-03-31    33.60    34.40   32.71     33.16   10675600     28.01342             NA
```

As you can see, the result of the `cbind` command introduces unwanted rows and the actual values from `sym.rank` are introduces in the unwanted rows.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: my bad, found the solution. Adding the following solves the issue:
ttz<-Sys.getenv('TZ')
Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')

But if anyone knows why, still here to listen to wisdom

Comment: If you don't supply a tz attribute you get your current timezome.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the "Indexed by objects..." portion of the `str()` output.

```
> str(A)
#...
Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC  # Date index, UTC timezone
> str(sym.rank)
#...
Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ:   # POSIXct index, no timezone
```

`Date` objects do not have a timezone, so they are always treated at UTC in the xts index.  `POSIXct` (and `POSIXlt`) objects *always* have a timezone.  When no timezone attribute is specified, your computer's current timezone is determined and used (how this is done depends on your OS and settings).

You don't say how you created `sym.rank`, but somehow you created it with a `POSIXct` index.  Since you only have daily data, you should use a `Date` index instead.  You can convert it via:

```
index(sym.rank) <- as.Date(index(sym.rank))
# now this should work without adding rows
merge(A, sym.rank)
```